Как поставить две системы на два диска?
У меня на пк есть два диска, на одном установлена винда, хотелось бы как то установить на другой диск линукс. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как?

бер да ставь. во время установки спросит на какой диск ставить

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

@eri я полный ноль в этом. Через какую программу или через что можно сделать это? Я пробовал через unetbootin, но при загрузке системы через него, выдаёт ошибку в Windows boot
